# Laravel [ErrorException] unserialize(): Error at offset 78 of 82 bytes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to queue a command in laravel. Using database as a queue driver. 
Dispatch happens fine and I can see the entry on the database. But when I run listen command from terminal

> php artisan queue:listen

Getting the following error:

```
  [ErrorException]                               
  unserialize(): Error at offset 78 of 82 bytes
```

Answer (score 5):

After 3 long hours of pulling my own hair, I was able to solve this. Posting the fix, in case, someone faces the same issue.

I was injecting Eloquent model into my Command and Laravel had a trouble serializing/deserializing the Eloquent model even after using `SerializesModels` trait.

Solution is to pass Eloquent object id, instead of entire object, and fetch back the object in handler using the id.